# Android reading all the values in a listview line by line

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-arrayadapter

I want to send normal sms to multiple numbers with different messages. Here I have retrieved the phone number and message to a listview. When I click the send button it should read all the rows in that listview line by line and messages should be send one by one. Can any one help me please. I know this coding is used for sending messages to one number. But I want to send multiple numbers in a listview.

```
String phoneNo = user_name.toString();
        String message = user_department.toString();
        try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "SMS faild, please try again.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
```

And this is my list array adapter.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE department='"+label+"'", null);

        userId.clear();
        user_name.clear();
        user_department.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID)));
                user_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
                user_department.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DEPARTMENT)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(home.this,userId, user_name, user_department);
        lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
        disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mCursor.close();
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a listview, the data is held by the `adapter`. so you have to loop through the adapter items to send messages.

Similar to the below code

```
for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
   sendMsg(adapter.getItem(i).number);
}
```

Here the `Adapter`, `getItem` returns the item at the position given. I hope you have the phone number in that object. Call the message sending method as many times you want to send the message. :-/

Comment: if the phone number and message is existed in each row means how will be the code?

Comment: still the data has to be stored in the adapter object right. since the rows get destroyed when we scroll down the list.

Comment: so what will do.consider iam a doctor and i getting lot of reservation for consultant.so i need to send their token number(this is my message) to each patient's mobile phone.that's what i am meant here

Comment: you need to only send message to all the numbers, whats the use of listview here then??

Comment: Doctor able to see the reserved patients in a particular date as listview.when he click the send button their token number(message) will be send to the patients mobile phone.so it should read token number(message) and phone number in a row,and send message,then should move to second row...like that,it should read all the rows in that listview.

Comment: the token number is generated already? or is the doctor entering it there?

Comment: no sir,its generated already(here id is considering as their token number),and i displayed it into listview

Answer (score 0):

```
Contract{

    String userName ;
    String userId ;
    String user_department ;
    String phoneNum ;
}



class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<Contract> mDatas ;
DisplayAdapter(Context context, List<Contract> datas) {
    mDatas = datas ;
}

// ......
}



SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE department='"+label+"'", null);

    List<Contract> datas = new ArrayList<Contract>();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contract newContract = new Contract();

            newContract.userId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID));
            newContract.userName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
            newContract.user_department = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DEPARTMENT));

            newContract.phoneNum = "set user's phone num";
            datas.add(newContract);
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(Home.this, datas);
    lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
    disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mCursor.close();




    // button click  and send msg.

    for(Contract contractItem : datas) {
        // send sms code method

    }
```